# Direct MagSafe charge from a MacBook Pro to another

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, magsafe

I know a Mac can charge another Mac with the correct USBC-USBC cable that can handle that power transmission.  However, can I plug the USB-C side of a MagSafe2 cable, that came with my M2 MBP, into my M2 MBP, then the MagSafe side to another MBP that support Mag Safe2 and that Mac will then charge off my MBP?

I don't think so, from what I am searching, in that there is a lack of this even being out there.  Seems only USBC-USBC (Mac to Mac) charging will work.

Please advise :-)

Comment: I don't think it will work (I can't test), but MagSafe 3 isn't a USB device interface meaning there's no negotiation happening between the adapter (must be PD compliant) and the MagSafe charge port.  MagSafe 3 uses the [1-wire protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Wire) to identify itself to the Mac, not USB.  Try plugging it in, the worst thing that will happen is that it doesn't work.